# How to check if connection from pool is free (not busy) for use? (nodejs with mariadb)

Tags: node.js, mariadb

Just curious is there a way to check if given connection busy or may be used? 
Or should/need i write own when question will stand.

On the app start:

- create pool of connection to mariadb (say **10 connections**)
- connections are written into Array
- on each Post/Get request i get next connection from connection array for work with, in a loop,
  there is a function for that:

  ```
  getNextConnection()
  ...
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    let conn = connArr[connNum];
  if (conn.isValid()) {
    resolve(conn);
  } else {
    conn.end();
  //Create a new connection and add it to the Array
    pool.getConnection().then((newConn) => {
    connArr.splice(connNum, 1, newConn);
    resolve(newConn);
  ...
  ```

All i have found are:

```
 - connection.ping() -> True
 - connection.isValid() -> Promise
```

both will work even if connection is busy and can't be used at this time.

But if some of the connections are busy for a long time and i have, say **100** requests per a second, i will get some busy connections for a new request.

Comment: Do you really need to do that? If not you can just call `pool.query` and it will use an idle connection. No need to manage that yourself. [docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections)

Comment: With long db queries and lot of requests, I got into issue, like, Max connection limit overcome, when use simple: pool.getConnection()

Comment: Do you release the connections when you are done? With `connection.release()`? So you are getting an error from mariadb? Your `connectionLimit`  in node is set too height then. (or your mariadb settings is too low.)

Comment: Sorry, i do not remember,  code was rewritten since that issue occurs. I will write a test for checking.

Comment: @RolandStarke From your: _Do you really need to do that?_ i guess it is no a good idea/practice to add connection into array and use them, are not i?

Comment: @RolandStarke And if i need all connections to be opened all the time. Just found that Release() does not close connection and simply return it to a pool: [poolgetconnection](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connector-nodejs-promise-api/#poolgetconnection-promise)

Comment: The pool itself is an array of connections, you can get a free connection with `pool.getConnection()` and when you are done working with the connection you call `connection.release()`, so that the next one can call `pool.getConnection()`. The connection is not closed so you should have 10 open connections after your app runs for a while (when 10 connections where needed at the same time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to check whether a connection is idle when you take it out from a pool.

These checks should be the responsibility of the connection pool implementation and any problems with it would most likely be caused by a bug in the pool implementation.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. The @Roland Starke also gave right description. Going to rewrite code and check it out.